# Magento2 - remove custom theme not composer

Tags: magento2, theme, uninstall

Magento2, testing stuff, and created custom themes, did not use composer, so how do I remove theme from system, command line uninstall themes does not seem to work, screenshot below: 
[image: attempt to uninstall theme from shell]

simply deleting the folders and clearing cache does not seem to do it.

Comment: Did you delete related files in the `pub/static` folder and also it should be removed from the theme table. Only themes installed via composer can be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after clearing `var/cache`, `var/generation`, `var/page_cache` and `pub/static/*` folders still you find it there, there is an entry for themes in database table `theme` with your theme info. Just delete the row containing your theme info and it will be gone from your system.

Comment: +1 since this worked for me.. But it's horrific!! Why is there not any simple command to do this?!? :O

Comment: Also, warning when clearing the `pub/static` folder: the `.htaccess` file should not be deleted (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)